# Git rebase branch onto older commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

Note: How this situation came to be is more of a tale that anything and not really relevant IMO.

Given the following git commit graph, starting from oldest, all pushed to origin

```
          start
            |
         breaking
       /          \
fix #0             work
    |               |
fix #1(master)     morework(issue-fix)
```

I need to move my branch (issue-fix) to be based on start, rather than breaking, that is turn it into

```
          start
       /         \
breaking            |
    |               |
fix #0             work
    |               |
fix #1(master)     morework(issue-fix)
```

The changes in breaking are unrelated to the issue fix (different part of project), hovever they cause the CI to fail for that branch, as the testing covers that part of the project as well.

I assumed a rebase would work, but after checking out morework, attempting it in SourceTree did nothing, manually running git rebase start just prints `Current branch issue-fix is up to date`

**Is there a clean and effiecient way of doing this? I don't want to make a new branch and move everything over manually if I don't have to.**

EDIT: Also, issue-fix has been pulled into another branch, thereby introducing the wrong commits there as well. Will the same process work there, or will doing it on issue-fix break that branch?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use interactive rebase to get rid of the `breaking` commit from your `issue-fix` branch.

In your case you should, checkout to the `issue-fix` branch and do:

`git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Then when the editor is open you should be able to choose which commits you want to leave and which you want to get rid of:

```
drop 2dsafa ... will delete the commit you want to get rid of
pick sdfsadf .. will leave this commit
pick dfsa4sdc .. will leave this commit
```

If your `issue-fix` branch have been already merged into other branches in its broken state, then things become a bit more complicated.

In such case I would suggest to use the interactive rebase to get rid of the `issue-fix` commits from those other branches. After that I would rebase the commits from those other branches on top of `issue-fix`.

Comment: So I comment out the lines for the breaking commit(s) and it will essentially kick it out of the branch? Sounds way easier than the whole new branch idea, thanks! Also, could you please check my edit if it's relevant to your solution?

Comment: I have fixed the answer. ;)

Comment: Check my extension of the answer. But as it's a slightly different topic, we can move to chat to discuss that.

Comment: Ok I first did the branch which pulled in from issue-fix. Seems to have worked, the graph looks correct. I may or may not have slightly screwed up at first, but that's not on you, point is, who needs cardio when you can mess with git history...

Answer (score 3):

```
git rebase --onto start work^ issue-fix
```

It tries to move the commits from `work`(included) to the tip of `issue-fix` onto the new base `start`.

If you want to skip or squash some of the commits, use the interactive mode with `-i`. The interactive page will show you how to.

If you want to keep merge commits, you could add `-p`. To keep empty commits, use `--keep-empty`.

You may have some other needs not mentioned in the question. But most probably you could find proper options in the manual of [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Comment: In fact I do have other needs (in a way). Edited in, do you wish to add anything based on that?

Comment: It only affects your local `issue-fix` by rewriting its history. For `issue-fix` in other repos (the remote repository, other developers' repositories, for example) and branches that have merged `issue-fix`, they are not affected. For the branches under your control, you can rewrite them as well. For those out of your control, you'll need to ask the maintainers to update their branches.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run interactive rebase for that.

On branch `issue-fix` run: `git rebase --interactive start`

This should pop-up the editor:

```
pick breaking <commit message>
pick work <commit message>
pick morework <commit message>
```

you should change "pick" from the first line to "drop" - i.e., you'd like to drop the `breaking` commit from your branch and rebase it top of `start`.
Save and close the editor.
Run `git log` to check the result.

As always, be careful as rebasing changes the commits hashes i.e. even though the commits `work` and `morework` *look* the same, their parents would have changed, causing their respective commit hashes to change.
This is potentially dangerous if `issue-fix` is a shared branch.

In case you are not sure whether someone already pulled your `issue-fix` branch, I'd go with `git revert breaking`.
This is a safe choice that does not mess up your branch history (it just adds another commit which "cancels out" `breaking`).

Comment: In fact I myself pulled issue-fix into another branch. Also on origin. Also needs to get rid of breaking (introduced by said pull). When speaking of `git revert breaking` you mean running it while on issue-fix? What will that do once merge time commes? Since fix #0,1 attempt to fix breaking by making more changes to make it a non-breaking change

Comment: yes - while on `issue-fix` run `git revert breaking` (where `breaking` is the SHA of your breaking commit).This will create another commit, let's name it `unbreaking` which is a "negative" of `breaking`. Given your situation, I'd go with this instead of the rebase (due to history changing issues discussed in my answer). You can then pull `issue-fix` into that other branch and it will have fixed the other branch as well.

Comment: Sorry, I totally ignored the last bit of your question. When merge-time comes, the revert approach would _potentially_ mess things up if someone else is working on the fix for `breaking` independently. There would probably be some merge conflicts and you'd have to be careful not to nullify any changes made by someone else in attempt to fix it.